# Data too long for column 'Dirty' at row 86 MySQL version 8.0.17

Tags: mysql

I have set as `longtext type` the field `contents` on the table `t_contents` stored a database `MySql version 8.0.17`

When call the webpage aspx on the browser I have this error

> Data too long for column 'Dirty' at row 86 MySQL

In the row 86 of field `contents` on the table `t_contents` are stored formatted html text , e.g.

```
<div>   <p>         &nbsp;</p>      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:259px;" width="0">       <tbody>             <tr>                <td nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="2" style="width:131px;height:20px;">                   <p align="center">                          Area</p>                </td>               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:64px;height:20px;">                    <p align="center">                          IcCO</p>                </td>               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="width:64px;height:20px;">                    <p align="center">                          ABC</p>                 </td>           </tr>
```

But the `longtext type` shouldn't have character limits or not?

How to do resolve this?

**table definition**

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| contents               | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_contents           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_image      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_image_link | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_ppt        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_ppt_link   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_xls        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_xls_link   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_pdf        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_content_pdf_link   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sUnity                 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sUnityName             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sMonthName             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sMonth                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sYear                  | int(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sDDHHMMUpdate          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sMatr                  | char(7)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID_contents_p         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sID                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: show as your table definition.

Comment: @rkosegi thanks, please see **table definition** in the qst

Comment: Error is complaining about column `Dirty` which is not present in your table.

Comment: @rkosegi if column Dirty is not present in my table, why the error?

Comment: How are you inserting data into table?

Comment: @rkosegi Yes the string contains HTML is inserted in the database. If empty the `column` contents I don't have error

Comment: do you have triggers on table?

Comment: @rkosegi no triggers on the table